# What is the correct way to initialize a Kivy Screen?

Tags: kivy

I am using Kivy with a .kv file. This is what my Python code looks like:

```
class WelconeScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.name='home'
        super(Screen,self).__init__(**kwargs)

class QuestionScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.name='question'
        super(Screen,self).__init__(**kwargs)

class RootScreen(ScreenManager):
    pass

class TestApp(App):
   def build(self):
        return RootScreen()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    appVar = TestApp()
    TestApp().run()
```

And this is my .kv file:

```
<RootScreen>:
    WelcomeScreen:
    QuestionScreen:

<WelcomeScreen>:
    Button:
        text: 'Download DB'
<QuestionScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text: 'My settings button'
        Button:
            text: 'Back to menu'
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'home'
```

Is this the correct way to initialize a Screen with Kivy? This works, but I am not sure the constructor is the right way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`name` is a kivy property, so you probably want to intialise it after calling super, not before.

You can also set it in kv instead, then you don't have to define an `__init__` just for this:

```
<WelcomeScreen>:
    name: 'home'
    Button:
        text: 'Download DB'
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted: to initialize the screen in my .kv file. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You write :
class WelconeScreen

But it's :
class  Welco**m**eScreen