# kivy screens. Do I have to initialize with super?

Tags: python, kivy, super

From the [docs](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html):

```
# Declare both screens
class MenuScreen(Screen):
    pass

class SettingsScreen(Screen):
    pass
```

From this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28527542/what-is-the-correct-way-to-initialize-a-kivy-screen):

```
class WelcomeScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Screen,self).__init__(**kwargs)
```

Under which circumstances is it necessary to initialize the screen with `super` and why ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Short answer:**

No you don't have to use super when defining a Screen.  Yes you do always have to `__init__` with super (if you use `__init__`).

**Longer answer:**

It's nothing unique to screens.  In the docs example, you aren't calling `__init__` and passing any parameters so no `super` is necessary.  You don't need an `__init__` call to define a Kivy Screen.  From the SO question, if you're running `__init__` you're passing **kwargs up the object hierarchy and also re-defining `__init__` which would normally run the initialization of the parent class.  `super` is used to allow you to pass **kwargs and run the parent `__init__` without an explicit call to the parent class, in this case, `Screen` inherits from `RelativeLayout`, which itself inherits from `FloatLayout`; without a super call you're overriding the parent class.

You don't need to call `__init__` unless you have some use for it.  Here is a `Screen` from one of my apps, with no `__init__` call (layout is set in the .kv file):

```
class LoginScreen(Screen):
    def login(self):
        self.parent.current = 'ParameterScreen'
```

You will use `__init__` if you want to set the layout, content, properties, etc. of a screen at the moment when you instantiate the class you have created without defining these things in the .kv file; to do that you will also need super as described above.  It's good practice in kivy though to use the .kv file when you can.

In this example, I want to be able to access BottomBar's parent with self.caller, which I pass in as a **kwargs when I create it, and have this be defined as soon as the bar is instantiated; so I need to define it in `__init__` which requires a super call.

```
class BottomBar(ActionBar):
    titletext = StringProperty('')
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        self.caller = kwargs.get('caller')
        super(BottomBar,self).__init__(**kwargs)
    def change_title(self,newtitle):
        self.titletext = newtitle
```

Comment: Does that mean, if I inherit without super like in this example: https://github.com/kivy/kivy/wiki/Data-driven-variables-with-kivy-properties, I can modify the root widget class and access variables which might be generated in the root widget during execution (e.g. variables obtained from a pipe object) ?

Comment: @Moritz If you are using __init__ you are overwriting the default initialization which will call the __init__ of the parent class and so on up the hierarchy.  You either need a super call or a BaseClass.__init__() named explicitly.  With super you can pass parameters to the parent class.