# How can a dynamic class access another class' attributes such as root.width/root.height?

Tags: kivy

Here is a class NewWindow with a GridLayout in a FloatLayout, a dynamic class NewButton inheriting from ToggleButton, and a class in the Python file that receives the GridProperty in order to add_widget NewButton into it.

The overall goal is to have a button that adds a toggle button into the grid layout, and for all button/toggle buttons to be able to dynamically change size for different screen resolutions. The issue I'm having is that I can't simply write `(root.width**2 + root.height**2) / 12**4` for NewButton. I think it's because "root" in NewWindow is not the same as "root" in NewButton, but I do not have a solution.

Is there a way for me to access NewWindow's "root" inside of NewButton? I ultimately just want all my buttons to match each other's sizes and for it to be dynamic, so I don't want to simply write a static "30" for font_size.

```
# File: main.kv
<NewWindow>:
    parentGrid: parentGrid
    FloatLayout:
        Button:
            text: "Add New Button"
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.05, "top": 0.7}
            size_hint: .4, 0.05
            font_size: (root.width**2 + root.height**2) / 12**4
            on_release:
                root.addButton()
        GridLayout:
            id: parentGrid
            cols: 1
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.5, "top": 0.7
            size_hint: .4, .5
<NewButton@ToggleButton>:
    text: "BUTTON"
    size_hint_y: ???
    #height: ???
    font_size: ???
    # Cannot simply use root.width or root.height, also size_hint: .4, 0.05 doesn't work

# File: MainApp.py
class NewWindow(Screen):
    parentGrid = ObjectProperty(None)
    def AddButton(self):
        self.parentGrid.add_widget(NewButton())
```

Answer (score 0):

You are right the two roots are different. One is as you say the size of the new window, but the other would only be the size of GridLayout. The problem you have with the size_hint is because you are using a GridLayout. If you can change to example a BoxLayout that would work if not the size_hint: None, None and then set the size: would work:

To get the the NewWindow Root use app.root.width and app.root.heigth

main.py:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.togglebutton import ToggleButton


class NewButton(ToggleButton):
    pass


class NewWindow(Screen):
    parentGrid = ObjectProperty(None)
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(NewWindow, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def addButton(self):
        print('test')
        self.parentGrid.add_widget(NewButton())


class Manager(ScreenManager):
    pass


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_file('test.kv')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

.kv:

```
Manager:
    NewWindow:
        name: 'new'

<NewButton@ToggleButton>:
    text: "BUTTON18"
    pos_hint: {"x": 0.05, "top": 0.7}
    size_hint_x: None
    size_hint: 1, 1
    #size: 10, 10
    font_size: (app.root.width**2 + app.root.height**2) / 12**4

<NewWindow>:
    parentGrid: parentGrid
    FloatLayout:
        Button:
            text: "Add New Button"
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.05, "top": 0.7}
            size_hint: .4, 0.05
            font_size: (root.width**2 + root.height**2) / 12**4
            on_release:
                root.addButton()
        BoxLayout:
            id: parentGrid
            cols: 1
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.5, "top": 0.7}
            size_hint: .4, .5
            canvas:
                Color:
                    rgba: 1,1,1,1
                Rectangle:
                    size: self.size
                    pos: self.pos
    # Cannot simply use root.width or root.height, also size_hint: .4, 0.05 doesn't work
```

I did also add the screenmanager to be able to access the width and height

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks so much for the help, using app.root.width and app.root.height fixed my issue!

Comment: Sorry I accidently clicked enter 
I have a few questions about your response.
Im curious why you overloaded the constructor for NewWindow? I read a bit about it on the docs but I'm not too sure what it's doing here.
Also, you mentioned that screenmanager gives you access to width and height, how does it do that? I don't see it being used outside of it's declaration in the py and kv file and app.root.width can be accessed without it
Thanks again for the help, I've been stuck for hours on this issue

Comment: No Problem. I just do it because I usually pass parameters into my screens so it is just habbit. But here is a good explanation I wouldn't have the characters to write it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40344081/kivy-screens-do-i-have-to-initialize-with-super if you check app.root you would see the it is the screen manager object at least in this case. And if you are running screens you should use the screenmanager so that you can add more screens and have something to handle the all the screens.